# zsh command not found :ls in macOS Big Sur

Tags: macos-big-sur

any command I typed said zsh: command not found
and  at first when I run terminal  said command not found: locale
and said
/Users/m-store/.zshrc:4: unmatched
[image]

Comment: It looks like your.zshrc is broken so your path is getting ruined.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this :

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:${PATH}
export PATH
```